# Outlook JS Add-In - "Permission to this message is restricted" on message read

Tags: office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

When a user reads a message and tries to activate my Add-In, they see "You cannot perform this action. Permission to this message is restricted". I can see that the user is encrypting their messages. Is it standard for JS Add-Ins to not work for encrypted messages? Or is there a permission setting in the manifest I can use to read emails securely via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is over here: [MSDN: Outlook add-ins on emails with digital signatures](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/89ec70df-4c98-4ce8-aba2-08c8191d8f27/outlook-addins-on-emails-with-digital-signatures?forum=appsforoffice)